# ScheduledExecuterService.scheduleAtFixedRate creating multiple thread pools - Android

Tags: java, android, dalvik, executorservice, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a `AsyncTask` called `UploadManager` in my Android Application, that checks for processed items, and uploads them to the server.
For this purpose I'm using the `ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate` to check for items after every 1 minute, and upload them to server.
However, at times, there are multiple pools of thread created (this happens like 10% of the times), due to which at times the same request is send twice to the server, though this concurrency is handled at both the server & client level, but I still don't want this to happen on the client side.
Below is how the code looks like.
In the MainActivity (start-activity), I initiate the UploadManager as:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       .
       .
       .
       new UploadManager().execute(this);
   }
}
```

`UploadManager` works as follows:

```
public class UploadManager extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, Integer> {

    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService;
    private static final int NUM_OF_THREADS = 5;
    private static final int DELAY_IN_SECONDS = 60;
    private Context context;
    private final Logger logger = new Logger(getClass().getSimpleName());

    protected Integer doInBackground(Context... context) {
        this.context = context[0];
        scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(NUM_OF_THREADS);
        scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(postInformation, 5, DELAY_IN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       return 0;
    }

    private Runnable postInformation = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (NetworkManager.isInternetAvailable(context)) {
                uploadAcknowledgement();
            }
        }
    };

    private void uploadAcknowledgement() {
        List<Acknowledgement> ackList = null;
        try {
            logger.info("RUNNING TASK TO POST ACKNOWLEDGEMENT");
            .
            .
        }
    }
}
```

When I checked the logs, it says:

```
35119 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  Upload Manager - [1363841355530] : 21/03/2013 10:19:15 : RUNNING TASK TO POST ACKNOWLEDGEMENT  
35122 [pool-3-thread-1] INFO  Upload Manager - [1363841355532] : 21/03/2013 10:19:15 : RUNNING TASK TO POST ACKNOWLEDGEMENT
```

Which clearly indicates that there are multiple pools of thread now, due to which, `uploadAcknowledgement()` method is called multiple-times.

The MainActivity is declared in AndroidManifest.xml as:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <activity android:name="MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    .
    .
```

Comment: Is it possible that your AsyncTask is getting called twice or the Activity which invokes it gets created more than once?

Comment: @asgs Actually, that Activity is the starting activity, I have included the manifest in the original post now.
The asyncTask `Upload Manager` will only be recreated, if the `MainActivity` is destroyed, which means, the entire application is destroyed (Please correct me, if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually figured out the reasons, if the `ScheduledExecutor`'s service runs overlap, then it spawns new worker threads (eg. in this case `postInformation()` creates a new worker thread) and eventually, a new pool.
However, multiple workers can be avoided by using [newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor%28%29) instead of `newScheduledThreadPool(int corePoolSize)'`.
So, instead of initialising `scheduledExecutorService' as:

```
scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(NUM_OF_THREADS);
```

It should have been be initialised as:

```
scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
```

This way it will be ensured that there are no multiple worker threads running.

Comment: Can't you set NUM_OF_THREADS = 1?

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of N number of files and started X number of threads to upload it without specifying which thread to pick which file.
One approach to solve this to add the files to be uploaded into a Blocking Queue and let the threads pick the files to be uploaded from the Queue. This way no file will be picked twice.